# How to automaticly add slugs to the new db objects?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I am using an external admin panel that is not connected to Django(but connected to the postgresql db), and as a result, when I add a new Work object through the admin, it does not automatically add a slug.

Is there a way to automatically check when a new object is created in the database and add a slug to it? Below is the code that I am currently using to add slugs:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk:
        slug_title = translit(self.ukrainian_title, 'uk', reversed=True)
        self.slug = slugify(slug_title)
        while Work.objects.filter(slug=self.slug).exists():
            self.slug = f"{slugify(slug_title)}-{get_random_string(length=4)}"
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And it's working perfectly, but with django default admin, not with the external one. Would appreciate any help